# Change of basis, Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I got a basis $B = \{u,v\}$ and a change of basis matrix, $P$, that takes us from $B$ to $C$.

$$u = (1,0,1,-1)$$
$$v = (1, 1 , 0, 1)$$

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}1& 2\\4& 3\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to figure out which vectors make up the basis $C$.

At first thought I multiplied $B$ with $P$ because I thought that would transform the basis from $B$ to $C$. However when checking the answer they used $P$ inverse to find the $C$.

Anyone got time to explain this (hopefully) simple problem?

Comment: If $C = \{w,z\}$ then $w = u + 4v$ and $z = 2u + 3v$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp That is exactly what i tried but according to an old exam the answer uses the inverse of P and then solve for C.

Comment: Then it is an issue of definition. How do you define the transfer matrix between two bases?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp On the exam they define the matrix as the change of basis  matrix from the base B to the base C

Comment: This is not a definition. How did you define it in the lecture? That's the point. Means: How did you define the "change of basis matrix from the base B to the base C". BTW, it is called **basis**, not **base**.

Comment: "Let B and C = [w1, ..... , wn] both be bases for a vector space V. The matrix P = ( [w1]B , .... , [wn]B) is called the change of coordinates matrix from C-coordinates to B-corordinates and satisfies [X]B = P [X]C"

Comment: How is [x]B defined for a vector x and a basis B? BTW: Here, you have "from C-coordinates to B-coordinates", but in the present problem, P is "from B to C".

Comment: "Suppose that B = {v1, ... , vn} is a basis for the vector space V. If x E V with x = x1v1 + x2v2 + .... + xnvn, then the coordinate vector of x with respect to the basis B is 

[x]B = (x1, x2, ..... , xn) "

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as Friedrich Philipp points out. When you quoted the actual problem statement for him, it said:

> Let $B$ and $C = [w_1, ..... , w_n]$ both be bases for a vector space $V$. The matrix $P = ( [w_1]B , .... , [w_n]B)$ is called the change of coordinates matrix from **$C$-coordinates to $B$-corordinates** and satisfies $[X]_B = P [X]_C$

But in your problem statement, you called it the change of coordinates matrix **from $B$ to $C$**, and treated it as such, when in fact, it goes the other way.

So if $[X]_B = P [X]_C$, then $[X]_C = P^{-1} [X]_B$. Thus the inverse.

Comment: The definitions in the comments are the exact definitions used in our lectures. However the problem is exactly as mentioned.

Comment: Then the way to go is as in my first post.